# How do I create an object using code in AS3 and give it a picture as display?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.*;
    public class declareImage extends Sprite
    {
        var ship:Sprite = new Sprite();
        public function declareImage()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I declared an object.
Now I want to give it a background as a picture from my Compute 
Should I use Sprite as data type or something else?

Comment: How are you importing the "picture from your computer"? Is it in your Flash document's library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. Of course, it's a very simple case (using fixed file name, etc), just to illustrate how to achieve what do you want and provide you the foundation to move on.

A tip, begin a class name with an uppercase letter.

```
 package 
 {
     import flash.display.Loader;
     import flash.display.Sprite;
     import flash.events.Event;
     import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
     import flash.net.URLRequest;

     public class DeclareImage extends Sprite 
     {
         private const IMAGE_URL:String = 'myImage.jpg';
         private var ship:Sprite;
         private var loader:Loader;

         public function DeclareImage() 
         {
             ship = new Sprite();
             addChild(ship);

             loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgressHandler, false, 0, true);
             loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler, false, 0, true);

             loader.load(new URLRequest(IMAGE_URL));
         }

         private function loadProgressHandler(event : ProgressEvent) : void 
         {
              trace('Loading: ' +  Math.round((event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal) * 100) + '%');
         }

         private function loadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void 
         {
              loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgressHandler);
              loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler);

              ship.addChild(loader);
              trace('complete');
         }

     }
 }
```